# Azure pipeline doesn't use specified compiler even though it is installed

Tags: c++, gcc, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an azure pipeline with a Microsoft-hosted agent that builds our c++ project for Linux, Mac and Windows. Because we use the std::filesystem library we needed to specify a higher GNU version in order to get it working on Mac and Linux. The issue is that while it works on Mac, Linux is still using gnu 7.5. How can we force Linux to use GNU 9.3 just like Mac?

We force the compiler version by setting the following variables in the .yaml:

```yaml
  variables:
    CC: gcc-9.3
    CXX: g++-9.3
    CXXFLAGS: -lstdc++fs
```

For our vmImages we use [platform]-latest,
this would mean that both Linux and Mac should have GNU 9.3 installed, as specified [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md)

**Here is our complete azure.pipeline.yaml**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

strategy:
  matrix:
    linux:
      imageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
    mac:
      imageName: 'macOS-latest'
    windows:
      imageName: 'windows-latest'

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)
  variables:
    CC: gcc-9.3
    CXX: g++-9.3
    CXXFLAGS: -lstdc++fs

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Clear build folder'
  inputs:
    script: 'rm -rf build'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Create build folder'
  inputs:
    script: 'mkdir build'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Setup vcpkg submodule'
  inputs:
    script: 'git submodule init'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Download vcpkg submodule'
  inputs:
    script: 'git submodule update'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Install vcpkg'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sh bootstrap-vcpkg.sh'
    workingDirectory: 'extern/vcpkg'

- task: CMake@1
  condition: ne( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
  inputs:
    cmakeArgs: '..'
    workingDirectory: 'build'

- task: CMake@1
  condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
  inputs:
    cmakeArgs: '.. -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64'
    workingDirectory: 'build'

- task: CMake@1
  displayName: 'CMake build'
  inputs:
    cmakeArgs: '--build build'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  condition: ne( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
  inputs:
    script: 'ctest --no-compress-output -T Test'
    workingDirectory: 'build'

- task: CmdLine@2
  condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT' )
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    script: 'ctest -C Debug --no-compress-output -T Test'
    workingDirectory: 'build'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'CTest'
    testResultsFiles: '**/Test*.xml'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-9.3`? CMake is a wonky when it comes to environment variables sometimes

Comment: I recommend you either specify an image that designates the version of the installed compilers or the install the compiler during the build pipeline. Although I typically do builds inside docker containers to eliminate all environmental differences. Also, I don't think you have the clean the build folders unless you are building on locally hosted agents.

Comment: @Mansoor Is that not what I am doing here? I set the compiler as a variable of the image

Comment: Have you checked whether that compiler is actually available on these VM images? You can add a step to output the version of gcc on the path? Typically only 1 version is installed. If so, then some like what @Firefly suggested should make it work for you. Long-term, to avoid any builds breaking due to environmental changes, it's always good to specify a specific version of an image or do the work to install the dependances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `'ubuntu-latest'`, GNU 9.3 is not installed. So Linux still uses GNU 7.5 after specifying the GNU version as 9.3.

To solve this issue, **You can change your `imageName` for linux from `'ubuntu-latest'` to `'Ubuntu-20.04'`.**

Then you can use GNU 9.3.

The followings are my YAML file for the test and its builds log.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-20.04'
  variables:
    CC: gcc-9.3
    CXX: g++-9.3
 
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      gcc –version
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, it is strange though for ubuntu-latest it should be installed as specified here: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md